# Statutory basis of Border agents' obligation to make "reasonable accommodations" for vulnerable individuals?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, immigration, travel, borders

In a brief but curtailed discussion with an immigration solicitor at a recent charity event, they began explaining that adults who were vulnerable due to mental illness, clearly palpable traumatization, or digital circumstances must be granted "reasonable accommodation" in encounters with UK border officers, along the lines of s55 safeguarding duties towards children. Sadly, the conversation was cut short before he could explain or give a statutory reference for this answer. What legal provisions are there that verge similarly to this idea?